Difference in maxima and minima of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$
Question : Given $$f(x)=\frac{\sin \pi x}{x^2}, x>0$$
Let $x_1<x_2<x_3<...<x_n<...$ be all points of local maximum of f.
Let $y_1<y_2<y_3<...<y_n<...$ be all points of local minimum of f.
Then prove that $|x_n-y_n|>1$ for every $n$.
(Source : JEE ADV 2019)
My attempt
As $$f'(x)=2\cos(\pi x)\dfrac{\dfrac{\pi x}{2}-\tan(\pi x)}{x^3}$$
Now qualitatively from the graph of $\tan(\pi x)$ and $\dfrac{\pi x}{2}$ and sign of derivative we can see that every alternate root of $\tan(\pi x)=\dfrac{\pi x}{2}$ is minima and maxima of the function (first non zero root being minima) and we can clearly see that
$$x_n\in(2n,2n+1/2)$$ $$y_n\in(2n-1,2n-1/2)$$ hence $$|x_n-y_n|>\dfrac{1}{2}$$ at the least. How to extend this bound to $1$ now...


Does there exist least local minima or local maxima? Anything missing in question?

there would be infinite local maximas and minimas

Is $x_1$ the least of all points of local maxima of $f$?

it is stated in the question @Yathi

No. My concern was, there cannot exist the least of all points of maxima. Similarly for minima as we get a point of maxima lesser than whatever point we chose. Isn't it?

Is it $\sin(\pi x)$ or $\sin(x)$ ?

@ClaudeLeibovici it is $\sin(\pi x)$

@Yathi in $x>0$ why can't there be a least point of maxima and minima

Oh. I missed that. Sorry.
